# Is using two partitions still better than not having them at all?

Tags: mysql, database-performance, database-partitioning

Consider having a table with some field holding only one of the three values; A, B and C. Surely defining an index over this field is useless as it's index cardinality is not sufficient. Instead it's a good case to use partitions.

The thing is in my case, I've got two types of queries; ones that only work with records of As and the others that work with As and Bs. If I define a partition for each value, queries working with As and Bs will need to make use of two partitions' indices.

So which one is better?

1. Defining an index on the field with no partitions.
2. Dividing the table into two partitions, with As and Bs in the same partition. Setting an index on the field.
3. Dividing the table to three partitions.

Comment: You do not provide enough information.  What is the relative proportion of As, Bs, and Cs?

Comment: Partitions aren't going to help much unless the tables are large, where large means they contain at least 10**7 rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Honestly I'm just designing the schema and guessing the proportions is hard for me but I think I can say that |A| < |B| < |C|. It would be nice if you could give an explanation why this proportion is important to you.

Comment: @OllieJones I'm not sure I follow! Breaking down any set into smaller ones should always be performant! Even if using partitions comes with some overhead, I think it would be of little significance. Unless your queries include more than one partition all the time.

Comment: "should always," eh? I've learned that intuition often is wrong when working with large scale data systems (such as MySQL). The developers of those systems are really skilled at clever data access. I've learned this the hard way sometimes, especially after wasting lots of time on partitioning solutions I imagined would help. Suggestion: develop your app, then optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

Partition criteria :
If table is greater than 5GB then you should go for partitioning else the results are not encouraging. [Tested on 100GB database ]

using DBMS_REDEFINITIION

Comment: I'm not sure what is DBMS_REDEFINITIION, but a quick search shows me that it has something to do with Oracle, in that case I must say I'm talking about MySQL. And it would be nice if you provide me with a reference for you claim, thanks.

Comment: My bad..I gave wrong reference..Yes. I am talking about Oracle.